PostgreSQL ERROR: extra data after last expected column (but column amount is the same)
I know this is not an uncommon question and I have been looking at the other questions.
But after reading through them I haven't been able to solve my problem.
I'm using PostgreSQL and want to fill my TPC-H tables i created with my generated table files. I filled all tables successfully with the following command except partsupp.
postgres=# COPY tpch1g.partsupp FROM '/home/user/TPC-H_1gb/partsupp.tbl' DELIMITER '|' CSV;

Then I get this Message:

ERROR:  extra data after last expected column CONTEXT:  COPY partsupp,
line 1: "1|2|3325|771.64|, even theodolites. regular, final
theodolites eat after the carefully pending foxes..."

As far as I understand this message tells me that the number of columns in the data does not match the expected number of columns for the partsupp table.
The partsupp table has 5 columns:
\d tpch1g.partsupp
                         Table "tpch1g.partsupp"
    Column     |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 ps_partkey    | integer                |           | not null | 
 ps_suppkey    | integer                |           | not null | 
 ps_availqty   | integer                |           |          | 
 ps_supplycost | numeric(15,2)          |           |          | 
 ps_comment    | character varying(199) |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "partsupp_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (ps_partkey, ps_suppkey)


and a line in my partsupp.tbl looks like this:

1|2|3325|771.64|, even theodolites. regular, final theodolites eat
after the carefully pending foxes. furiously regular deposits sleep
slyly. carefully bold realms above the ironic dependencies haggle
careful|

It has the same amount of columns so I don't get what went wrong. My copy command worked for the other tables perfectly. Is there something i did wrong or overlooked?

You should format you snippets of err message and input in a way which preserves whitespace.

your sample from partsupp.tbl ends with a separator, so there is an extra column of data not matching the table structure.
